# Inverse modulo certain numbers.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, integers, gcd-and-lcm

Let $b,n$ be given positive integers. I would like to give some formula for the multiplicative inverse $a^*$ of a positive integer $a$ to a modulo of the form $4ab-n$, where $(a,n)=1$, i.e.

$$
aa^*\equiv1(\mod 4ab-n)
$$

If $n=1$ it is easily seen that $a^*=4b$, but I could not find a simple formula in general.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that there's a simple formula since there's none when $b=0$ (I know that you assume $b>0$.)  Possible help: the extended Euclidean algorithm for the pair $(a, 4ab-n)$ should reduce to that for $(a,n)$ after one division by $a$.

Answer (score 1):

If it were possible we'd get a general formula for $\,a^{-1}\pmod n,\,$  since by Bezout

$$ 1\, =\, i(4ab-n) + j a\, =\, a(4ib+j) - i n$$

Therefore $\ j\equiv a^{-1}\pmod{4ab-n}\ \Rightarrow\ j+4ib\equiv a^{-1}\pmod n$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally this yields $\, a^{-1}\!\!\pmod{\! n}\,$ from $\,a^{-1}\!\!\pmod{\!kn +\, \ell a}$